# Macros not working in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of macros that were set up in Excel 2003 then continued to work when in Excel 2010. However, now I have moved to Excel 2013, they fail to work. Error is:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
>   Method 'Insert' of object 'Range' failed

One of the macros is the following:

```
'Unprotect
Sheets("Appraisal").Unprotect "*********"

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer

    x = Range("cashflowformulas:endcashflow").Columns.Count
    y = Range("projectduration").Value

If x - 1 < y Then
If y - x > 10 Then

    Do
    z = z + 1

   'Copy first column of cashflow formulas
    Range("cashflowformulas").Copy

    'Insert copied cells at end of cashflow to give additional project months
    Range("endcashflow:offset(endcashflow,,10-1)").Insert shift:=xlToRight

    Loop Until z > (y - x) / 10 - 1

End If

    'Copy first column of cashflow formulas
    Range("cashflowformulas").Copy

    'Insert copied cells at end of cashflow to give additional project months
    Range("endcashflow:offset(cashflowformulas,,sum(projectduration)-1)").Insert shift:=xlToRight


ElseIf y > 0 Then
If x - 1 > y Then
If MsgBox("Cashflow data beyond the new project duration will be permanently deleted. Do you want to proceed?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
'Remove cashflow months after project end date
    Range("offset(endcashflow,,-1):offset(cashflowformulas,,sum(projectduration))").Delete
Else
Range("projectduration").Formula = x - 1
MsgBox "Operation cancelled"
End If
End If
End If


'Reprotect
Sheets("Appraisal").Protect "simonproof", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True


End Sub
```

`"ProjectDuration"` is a single cell, whereas the other named ranges are columns e.g. `"Appraisal!$S:$S"`

I have tried changing `Insert shift:=xlToRight` to `Insert shift:=xlShiftRight` 
and `Insert shift:=xlDown` to `Insert shift:=xlShiftDown` but on debugging I still get caught at:

```
Range("endcashflow:offset(cashflowformulas,,sum(projectduration)-1)").Insert shift:=xlShift50Right
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's `xlShift50Right`??

Answer (score 0):

Change `shift:=xlToRight` to `(xlToRight)`.

See new code below

```html
'Unprotect
Sheets("Appraisal").Unprotect "*********"

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer

    x = Range("cashflowformulas:endcashflow").Columns.Count
    y = Range("projectduration").Value

If x - 1 < y Then
If y - x > 10 Then

    Do
    z = z + 1

   'Copy first column of cashflow formulas
    Range("cashflowformulas").Copy

    'Insert copied cells at end of cashflow to give additional project months
    Range("endcashflow:offset(endcashflow,,10-1)").Insert (xlToRight)

    Loop Until z > (y - x) / 10 - 1

End If

    'Copy first column of cashflow formulas
    Range("cashflowformulas").Copy

    'Insert copied cells at end of cashflow to give additional project months
    Range("endcashflow:offset(cashflowformulas,,sum(projectduration)-1)").Insert (xlToRight)


ElseIf y > 0 Then
If x - 1 > y Then
If MsgBox("Cashflow data beyond the new project duration will be permanently deleted. Do you want to proceed?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
'Remove cashflow months after project end date
    Range("offset(endcashflow,,-1):offset(cashflowformulas,,sum(projectduration))").Delete
Else
Range("projectduration").Formula = x - 1
MsgBox "Operation cancelled"
End If
End If
End If


'Reprotect
Sheets("Appraisal").Protect "simonproof", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing and found a solution [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/754872-method-insert-object-range-failed-run-time-error-2147417848-80010108-a.html)

Apparently adding a line before the copy command that clears an arbitrary cell solves the problem.

```
'Dummy clear statement:
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Clear

'Copy first column of cashflow formulas
Range("cashflowformulas").Copy

'Insert copied cells at end of cashflow to give additional project months
Range("endcashflow:offset(endcashflow,,10-1)").Insert shift:=xlToRight
```